# Slow writes to harddrive, software or hardware problem?

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, ssd, io

I have a problem where my Ubuntu (17.10 right now, but it's been doing it for several releases) freezes when I write to my SSD disk, and I need to find out whether it's a software problem or if my SSD is dying on me. I'm running Ubuntu on an Asus UX31E laptop. I'm using full disk encryption (configured automatically using the installer).

I've tested the read speed like this:

```
$ sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt 

/dev/mapper/sda5_crypt:
 Timing cached reads:   9228 MB in  2.00 seconds = 4618.04 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 1190 MB in  3.00 seconds = 396.46 MB/sec
```

That looks like decent numbers to me, let's try writing to the disk:

```
$ LC_ALL=C dd if=/dev/zero of=~/out.bin bs=100M count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB, 100 MiB) copied, 16.882 s, 6.2 MB/s
```

Wow, this is really slow. It shouldn't take this long despite it being an encrypted (512 bit aes-xts-plain64) partition, right? I can't do anything while I write to the disk, it becomes totally unresponsive. I can't even move the mouse pointer.

I'm using the deadline scheduler:

```
$ cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler 
noop [deadline] cfq
```

I want to verify that this is a hardware problem, so that I don't waste money on a new SSD. How do I determine the root cause of the unresponsiveness?

## EDIT1:

smartctl output:

```
[...]
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       6160
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4420
171 Program_Fail_Count      0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Avg_Write/Erase_Count   0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       84
174 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4379
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
230 Perc_Write/Erase_Count  0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       280
232 Perc_Avail_Resrvd_Space 0x0003   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
234 Perc_Write/Erase_Ct_BC  0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       436
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       10526182882
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       9359492632
[...]
Warning! SMART Self-Test Log Structure error: invalid SMART checksum.
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Interrupted (host reset)      70%     64397         -
# 2  Short offline       Interrupted (host reset)      50%     18010         -
# 3  Short offline       Interrupted (host reset)      70%     31469         -
# 4  Short offline       Interrupted (host reset)      60%     26654         -
# 5  Short offline       Interrupted (host reset)      70%     10910         -
# 6  Short offline       Interrupted (host reset)      70%     58379         -
```

I also tried to force a self-test (multiple times) by booting from a live CD and running `smartctl -t short -C /dev/sda` and waiting significantly longer than the specified time. However, when I tried to view the result, I couldn't:

```
$ smartctl -a /dev/sda
[...]
A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options*
[...]
```

Comment: You can inspect if your drive is failing by using smartctl (package smartmontools), here are some hints : https://superuser.com/a/1037650/201468

Comment: I've updated my question, @pim, in order to provide some more detail. I really don't know how to interpret this data.

Comment: I don't know about SSD, but usually the conventional hard drives become slow before dead. So whatever the reason make a backup copy of the important data is a good idea!

Comment: Don't worry, I already have everything imortant and unimportant backed up.

Comment: Some HDD and SSD vendors provide some documentation about the smart attributes of there drive, try to google your drive make/model, or post the vendor+model here.